# How to implement checkmark on dropdown menu like "Files" app on swift

Tags: swift, uikit, dropdown

I am trying to make an app in which you can choose between list mode and grid mode, just like the files app. I have found the UIAlert .state method in which you can choose on or off. My question is that how does on toggle the checkmark to show when the users chooses list or grid mode respectively? I have made a function in which it refreshes the menu given a boolean factor but the button UI does not update. How can I approach this?

unfortunately I am new at swift and stack overflow and the site won't allow me to post pictures just yet....BUT a member has notified me to post code instead (of course!) and here it is! So how does on change the state from .on to .off once a user chooses list or grid mode

```
private func getMenuState() -> UIMenu {
    if isListMode {
        
        let menu = UIMenu(title: "",children: [
            UIMenu(title: "Menu1",options: .displayInline, children: [
                    UIAction(title: "New Collection", image: UIImage(systemName: "plus")) { (action) in
                        //Handle Code
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Name Your Collection", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)
                        alert.textFields?.first?.autocapitalizationType = .words
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
                            guard let field = alert.textFields?.first, let text = field.text?.capitalized, !text.isEmpty else {
                                return
                            }
                            self?.createNewCollection(name: text)
                        }))
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true)
                    },
                    UIAction(title: "Edit Collection", image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil")) { (action) in
                        // Handle code
                    }]), UIMenu(title: "",options: .displayInline, children: [UIAction(title: "List View", image: UIImage(systemName: "line.horizontal.3"),state: .on, handler: { (action) in
                        self.isListMode = true
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }),
                    UIAction(title: "Icons View", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.grid.4x3.fill"),state: .off, handler: { (action) in
                        self.isListMode = false
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    })
                    
                    ])
        ])
        return menu
    } else {
        let menu = UIMenu(title: "",children: [
            UIMenu(title: "Menu1",options: .displayInline, children: [
                    UIAction(title: "New Collection", image: UIImage(systemName: "plus")) { (action) in
                        
                    },
                    UIAction(title: "Edit Collection", image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil")) { (action) in
                        // Handle code
                    }]),
            
            UIMenu(title: "",options: .displayInline, children: [
                UIAction(title: "List View", image: UIImage(systemName: "line.horizontal.3"),state: .off, handler: { (action) in
                    
                    self.isListMode = true
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }),
                UIAction(title: "Icons View", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.grid.4x3.fill"),state: .on, handler: { (action) in
                    self.isListMode = false
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }),
                
            ])
        ])
        
        return menu
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please add your code.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Don’t post pictures. Post your code, and format it using code tags (the `{}` button.) You can paste a link to a picture of your UI if you want, but showing and explaining your current code is more important.

Comment: Thank you guys for your reply! I have added the code I've been using for now! So basically trying to get the state to toggle if list mode or grid mode by determining if a boolean isListMode is true or false. I also tried state: isListMode ? .on : .off and yet no change once the action is called

Comment: You have to rebuild the menu dynamically. See https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/604368f458076dd40a8f4d0676a2aa79adb8e390/bk2ch12p595NewButtons/NewButtons/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

I implemented your function through private variables. ("_state")

##### Example：

```
import UIKit
import SwiftExpand

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
class MenuActionChooseOneController: UIViewController {

    var menuData: [(String, [(String, UIImage?)])] {
        return [
            ("Menu", [
                (title: "选择", image: UIImage.checkmark_circle),
                (title: "新建文件夹", image: UIImage.folder_badge_plus),
                (title: "扫描文档", image: UIImage.doc_text_viewfinder),
                (title: "连接服务器", image: UIImage.rectangle_connected_to_line_below),
                ]
            ),
            ("Menu1", [
                (title: "图标", image: UIImage.square_grid_2x2),
                (title: "列表", image: UIImage.list_bullet),
                ]
            ),
            
            ("Menu2", [
                (title: "名称", image: UIImage.chevron_up),
                (title: "日期", image: UIImage.chevron_down),
                (title: "大小", image: UIImage.chevron_left),
                (title: "种类", image: UIImage.chevron_right),
                (title: "标签", image: nil),
                ]
            ),
        ]
    }
    
    lazy var menuBtn: UIButton = {
        let sender = UIButton(type: .custom)
        sender.setTitle("menu", for: .normal);
        sender.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        sender.menu = UIMenu.map(data: menuData, handler: { action in
            switch action.title {
            case "图标", "列表":
                action.handleStateChange(sender, section: 1, isSingleChoose: true) {
                    DDLog(sender.checkRow(by: 1))
            //        DDLog(sender.checkActions(by: 1))
                    let tmp = sender.checkActions(by: 1)
                    DDLog(tmp?.map({ $0.title }))
                }

            case "名称", "日期", "大小", "种类", "标签":
                action.handleStateChange(sender, section: 2, isSingleChoose: false) {
                    DDLog(sender.checkRow(by: 2))
            //        DDLog(sender.checkActions(by: 2))
                    let tmp = sender.checkActions(by: 2)
                    DDLog(tmp?.map({ $0.title }))
                }
                
            default:
                DDLog(action.title)
            }
        })
        return sender
    }()
    
    
    var isListMode: Bool{
        guard let row = menuBtn.checkRow(by: 1) else { return true }
        return row == 1
//        guard let menu1 = self.menuBtn.menu?.children[1] as? UIMenu,
//              let value = menu1.children[0].value(forKey: kActionState) as? Int
//              else { return true }
//        return value == 1
    }
    // MARK: -lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        edgesForExtendedLayout = []
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        title = "MenuActionChooseOne"
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuBtn)
    }
    
    // MARK: -funtions

}
```

##### UIMenu+Helper

```
/// UIAction: "_state"
public let kActionState = "_state"

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
public extension UIMenu{

    /// Data mapping UIMenu structure
    static func map(_ title: String = "", data: [(String, [(String, UIImage?)])], handler: @escaping UIActionHandler) -> UIMenu {
        return UIMenu(title: title, children: data.map {
            UIMenu(title: $0.0, options: .displayInline, children: $0.1.map({
                    return UIAction(title: $0.0, image: $0.1, handler: handler)
                })
            )
        })
    }
}

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
public extension UIAction{
    
    /// state change(.on/.off), Support single selection/multiple selection.
    func handleStateChange(_ sender: UIButton, section: Int, isSingleChoose: Bool, handler: (()->Void)?) {
        guard let menu = sender.menu?.children[section] as? UIMenu else { return }
        if isSingleChoose == false {
            if self.state == .off {
                self.setValue(1, forKey: kActionState)
            } else if self.state == .on {
                self.setValue( 0, forKey: kActionState)
            }
        } else {
            menu.children.forEach {
                $0.setValue($0 == self ? 1 : 0, forKey: kActionState)
            }
        }
        handler?()
    }
}


@available(iOS 14.0, *)
public extension UIButton {
        
    /// Actions (Support single selection/multiple selection)
    /// - Returns: row(state is on)
    func checkActions(by section: Int) -> [UIAction]?{
        guard let sectionMenu = menu?.children[section] as? UIMenu
              else { return nil }
        
        let firters = sectionMenu.children.filter {
            guard let action = $0 as? UIAction,
                  let value = action.value(forKey: kActionState) as? Int else { return false }
            return value == 1
        }
        return firters as? [UIAction]
    }
    
    /// row(Support single selection)
    /// - Returns: row(state is on)
    func checkRow(by section: Int) -> Int?{
        guard let sectionMenu = menu?.children[section] as? UIMenu
              else { return nil }
        
        let firters = sectionMenu.children.filter {
            guard let value = $0.value(forKey: kActionState) as? Int else { return false }
            return value == 1
        }

        guard let checkAction = firters.first as? UIAction else { return nil }
        return sectionMenu.children.firstIndex(of: checkAction)
    }
    
}
```

[Blog](https://juejin.cn/post/6982050059500126221)

[Github](https://github.com/shang1219178163/SwiftTemplet/blob/develop/SwiftTemplet/Controllers/MenuActionChooseOneController.swift)

Comment: Thanks so much Bin!! I can't wait to go home and try out the code!! Much appreciated brother! Thank you

Comment: If it helps you, please vote up for this answer. I need some reputation to increase the answer permission.@Mehrad88

Comment: Hey Bin, I had upvoted it the moment I read though it! But I'm new to stack overflow and it says I need 15 reputation points before I can upvote!! Im almost there! ill come back and upvote yours when I am, promise

Comment: What a sad story! But it’s still fun to help you.@Mehrad88